# Accessing Apple IR Receiver with C# (Windows 7 in bootcamp)?

Tags: c#

My school gave us MacBook Pros when we were accepted. I bought an IR remote for it later and I have the IR receiver (built in) working normally on itunes and other apps that accept input from it. I want to receive input from the remote in my own programs and I have no idea how to do that.

I've looked and a lot of examples talk about using the System.Net.Ports.SerielPort class but when I look under device manager it says that the IR receiver is connected via USB and I don't believe the SerielPort can access a USB device (although I know very little about the class).

What APIs are available that would help me receive input from the IR Receiver that's appearantly plugged into USB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is an [HID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_interface_device) device (you should be able to confirm in the device manager)then you can look at [this project](http://www.charltonfamily.net/software/ccusbhid/) for an example of how I used Windows API to access another USB HID device. You'll still need information on the IR receiver itself to know how it's commands work.